# angular 9 add constructor parameter, then html render not correctly

Tags: angular, constructor, ng-content, ng-container, angular9

I create a component in angular 9, and I use  in the component to inject the html. so far, it's still very normal ( render html correctly). but after I add parameter in constructor, then the html in component not render in browser, only render the ng-container content in the browser. how can i do?

I have tried to remove constructor parameter, then the component render correctly.. but i need to import render2 and elementRef in component, so I cannot do this way

```
Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.900.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.0-next.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.0-next.5
@angular/cli                       9.0.0-next.5
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.0-next.5
@schematics/angular                9.0.0-next.5
@schematics/update                 0.900.0-next.5
ng-packagr                         5.5.1
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.40.2
```

myComponent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '[nav-item]',
  templateUrl: './myComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myComponent.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
....
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log('hee',_renderer);
  }
```

myComponent.component.html

```
<div class="nav_list_item--level1" >
    <a href="#" #navItemContent class="nav_list_item_content nav_list_item_content--level1"  >
        <ng-content select="[nav-content]"></ng-content>
    </a>
    <div #navItemDetail class="nav_list_item_detail nav_list_item_detail--level1">
        <ng-content select="[nav-detail]"></ng-content>
    </div> 
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<div nav-item>
   <ng-container nav-content>
      content text
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container nav-detail>
      <div style="width: 800px;">
        detail detail text
      </div>           
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

but when render in chrome 
the html in component not render in browser....

```
<div nav-item>
content text
<!--ng-container-->
detail detail text
<!--ng-container-->
</div>
```

the correct render is like following

```
<div nav-item>
<a href="#" #navItemContent class="nav_list_item_content nav_list_item_content--level1"  >
        content text
    </a>
    <div #navItemDetail class="nav_list_item_detail nav_list_item_detail--level1">
        detail detail text
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question here? What have you done so far?

Comment: my html in component not render in browser after i add constructor parameter. the correct rendrer is  like 
<div nav-item>
<a href="#" #navItemContent class="nav_list_item_content nav_list_item_content--level1"  >
        content text
    </a>
    <div #navItemDetail class="nav_list_item_detail nav_list_item_detail--level1">
        detail detail text
    </div> 
</div>

Comment: errors in console??

Comment: has one error but I think it is not related about this problem 
ng-validate.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: ng.probe is not a function
    at Object.e.isDebugMode (ng-validate.js:1)
    at l (ng-validate.js:24)
    at Object.602 (ng-validate.js:24)
    at r (ng-validate.js:1)
    at Object.603 (ng-validate.js:24)
    at r (ng-validate.js:1)
    at ng-validate.js:1
    at ng-validate.js:1

Except this, no error in console

Comment: Mind you share your code on https://stackblitz.com